# How to optimize D3 animation for tens of thousands of elements?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js, graph, graph-theory

I am writing a BEng on visualizing the structure of the internet using graphs.

Problem that I am facing is that my graph database has around 50k records, and I want to render all of those records using force-directed graph technique. For this purpose I am using "react-force-graph-2d" NPM library, which is a D3 wrapper.

When I try to render this graph on my desktop machine, I am getting seconds per frame instead of frames per second.

What techniques could I try, in order to optimize rendering of the D3 animation with tens of thousands elements?

Comment: IMHO you need to prune your dataset so as to show what is significant.  Trying to display 50K items on a screen all at once will just be a meaningless mess.  You will have better lick stepping back and considering what it is you want to display.

Comment: @ravenspoint I want to display the general structure of my graph data. I do not know if it is possible to filter the data. I could probably remove nodes from the same domain (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Outlines) But what I am looking for here is some "hacks" for optimizing the rendering of large datasets.

Comment: Is this [the library](https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph) you are using?  My first suggestion was to make sure you are rendering on a canvas instead of SVG but it looks like canvas is the implementation for that library.  You didn't provide any source code, but the author of the library [provides an example with 75K nodes](https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph/blob/master/example/large-graph/index.html) that runs OK on my PC.

Comment: @Mark I am using this library - https://github.com/vasturiano/react-force-graph

Comment: @Mark this is the repository, but without the database - https://github.com/mbledkowski/interwebs/tree/main/interface

Comment: You could probably ask the researchers/designers who created the [Six Degrees of Francis Bacon](http://www.sixdegreesoffrancisbacon.com/) visualization, they managed to do a good job (well, it is not very fast to be honest, but worth a try). According to BuiltWith, they used Angular